Sum the series $\frac{x}{2!(n-2)!} + \frac{x^2}{5!(n-5)!} + \frac{x^3}{8!(n-8)!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{n/3}}{(n-1)!}$
Duplicate of To find the sum: $\frac {1}{n!} \sum \binom {n}{2+3r} x^{1+r}$ .
I'll search better before posting next time!
Also, I made a mistake, when applying the roots of unity. I should have divided everything by 3, and the final answer is
$$\frac{x^{1/3}}{3\cdot n!}((1+x^{1/3})^n+(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)(1+x^{1/3}(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i))^n+(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)(1+x^{1/3}(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i))^n)$$

I'm going through Hardy's "Pure Mathematics" and found a very interesting problem. This is probably the hardest problem I solved so far, so I want to share it in case someone will look for it. Also, I'm wondering if there is a better and simpler approach that I missed, and I'm happy to hear any feedback on how I presented my work(it's my first post here).
The problem is to sum the series (for n being a multiple of 3):
$$\frac{x}{2!(n-2)!} + \frac{x^2}{5!(n-5)!} + \frac{x^3}{8!(n-8)!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{n/3}}{(n-1)!}=$$
First, if we multiply everything by $n!$ then the constants look like binomial coefficients.
$$=\frac{1}{n!}(\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}x + \frac{n!}{5!(n-5)!}x^2 + \frac{n!}{8!(n-8)!}x^3 + \cdots + \frac{n!}{(n-1)!}x^{n/3})=$$
$$=\frac{1}{n!}(\binom{n}{2}x + \binom{n}{5}x^2 + \binom{n}{8}x^3 + \cdots + \binom{n}{n-1}x^{n/3})=$$
$$=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n/3-1}\binom{n}{2+3k}x^{k+1}= $$
The above summation looks very similar to binomial expansion, except some terms are missing. So, I took indices 0,1,2...n and used the 3rd root of unity to single out 2nd, 5th, 8th...(n-1) terms. Of course, I changed the power of x to make sure it is of the right magnitude for the terms we are singling out.
$$=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{(k+1)/3}(1+w_3^{k+1}+w_3^{2(k+1))})=$$
$$=\frac{1}{n!}(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{(k+1)/3}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{(k+1)/3}w_3^{k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{(k+1)/3}w_3^{2(k+1)}=$$
Next, factor out what ever we can, and combine $x$ and $w$ under one power $k$
$$=\frac{x^{1/3}}{n!}(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{k/3}+w_3\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{k/3}w_3^{k}+w_3^2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{k/3}w_3^{2k})=$$
$$=\frac{x^{1/3}}{n!}(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(x^{1/3})^k+w_3\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(x^{1/3}w_3)^k+w_3^2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(x^{1/3}w_3^2)^k)=$$
Now, we simply have three binomial distributions
$$=\frac{x^{1/3}}{n!}((1+x^{1/3})^n+w_3(1+x^{1/3}w_3)^n+w_3^2(1+x^{1/3}w_3^2)^n)=$$
Lastly, we need to find the third root of unity and plug it in.
$$w_3=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i \qquad w_3^2=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$$
$$=\frac{x^{1/3}}{n!}((1+x^{1/3})^n+(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)(1+x^{1/3}(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i))^n+(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)(1+x^{1/3}(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i))^n)$$

Mathematica:  $$\frac{,
_3F_2\left(-\frac{n}{3}-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}-\frac{n}{3},-\frac{n}{3};\frac{2}{3}, \frac{4}{3};-x\right)-1}{(n+1)!}$$ which uses the generalized hypergeometric function, $\mbox{}_p F_q (a; b; z)$.

This question is similar to: To find the sum: $\frac {1}{n!} \sum \binom {n}{2+3r} x^{1+r}$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found from it being mentioned in Tim's answer.

@DavidG.Stork Thank you, I'm going to look into this idea!

@JohnOmielan It is a duplicate. Sorry, I'll search for similar questions better next time.

Your derivation of the sum is great!
Just some minor comments. First, the sum in question is finite, so it is just a polynomial in $x$, and hence no analysis (in the mathematical sense) is necessary to study it. The key to finding a closed-form expression for the sum is, as you have spotted, to use the 3rd roots of unity $\mu_3 = \{1,\omega_3,\omega_3^2\}$ (where $\omega_3 = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$). This is because you can detect the exponent of $z^k$ modulo $3$ by the fact that $(\omega_3.z)^k = \omega_3^kz^k = \omega^r z^k$ for a unique $r \in \{0,1,2\}$. That is:
Key observation: the function $z\mapsto z^k$ when composed with $z \mapsto \omega_3.z$ becomes the function $z\mapsto \omega_3^r.z^k$.
Now if $n=3k$ is a multiple of $3$ and we let $b(z) = (1+z)^n$ then by the binomial theorem we have
$$
\begin{split}
b(z) &= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} z^i \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{3k}{3j}z^{3j} + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{3k}{3j+1} z^{3j+1} + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{3k}{3j+2} z^{3j+2}\\
&= n!(b_0(z)+b_1(z)+b_2(z))
\end{split}
$$
where the $b_i$ are given by the three sums in the preceding line, so that in particular,
$$
b_2(z) =\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{z^{3j+2}}{(3j+2)!(n-3j-2)!} = z^{-1}\sum_{l=1}^{k}\frac{(z^3)^k}{(3l-1)!(3(k-l)+1)!}
$$
and hence $zb_2(z) = s(z^3)$ where $s(x)$ is the sum we are trying to compute. Note that $w \mapsto zb_2(z)$ where $z^3=w$ is a well-defined function of $w$ despite the fact that you must choose a cube root of $w$ to calculate it: this is clear from the series expression for $zb_2(z)$, or alternatively, by noting that if $w=z^3$ then if $z_1^3=w$ is any other choice, we have $z_1 = \omega_3^k.z$ for some $k \in \{0,1,2\}$ and
$$
\omega_3^k z.b_2(\omega_3^k z) = (\omega_3^{k}\omega_3^{2k}) z.b_2(z) = z.b_2(z).
$$
Now by the key observation, we have
$$
b(\omega_3 z) = \frac{1}{n!}(b_0(z) + \omega_3 b_1(z) + \omega_3^2 b_2(z)),
\quad b(\omega_3^2 z) = \frac{1}{n!}(b_0(z) + \omega_1^2 b_1(z) + \omega_3 b_2(z)),
$$
and since $1+\omega_3 + \omega_3^2=0$ it follows that
$$
b(z)+\omega_3 b(\omega_3 z)+ \omega_3^2 b(\omega_3^2 z) = \frac{3b_2(z)}{n!}
$$
Now the OP gets to this expression by introducing the factor $1+\omega_3^k+ \omega_3^{2k}$ into the terms of the binomial expression for $(1+x)^{3k}$, using the fact that $1+\omega_3^k + \omega_3^{2k} =0$ if $k$ is not a multiple of $3$ and is equal to $3$ when $k$ is a multiple of $3$. The derivation above shows that what is necessary for this approach to work is that the matrix
$$
D_3(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & t & t^2 \\ 1 & t^2  & t^4\end{bmatrix}
$$
is invertible when $t =\omega_3$. But this is a Vandermonde matrix and its determinant is $(t-1)(t^2-1)(t^2-t) = t(t-1)^3(t+1)^2$, and hence is nonvanishing at $\omega_3$. (The particular method of inverting this matrix used by the OP is a manifestation of the finite Fourier transform for $\mathbb F_3$, the field of 3 elements).
It follows that
$$
s(x) = \frac{z.n!}{3}\left((1+z)^n + \omega_3(1+\omega_3 z)^n + \omega_3^2(1+\omega^2 z)^n\right)
$$
where $z^3 =x$. Note that this "closed form" expression for the series requires one to choose a cube root of $x$, despite the fact that the value of the expression is independent of the choice of cube root.

Thank you so much, I feel I can learn a lot from your answer!

In the line where you introduce roots of unity note that when $k\equiv 2 \mod 3$ the expression
$$
1 + \omega_3^{k+1} + \omega_3^{2(k+1)}
$$
sums up to $3$. Thus if we want the sum in this line to equal the preceding sum, a factor of $\frac{1}{3}$ must be added in front. This also changes the final answer by a factor of $\frac{1}{3}$.
Ignoring this minor mistake, I find your solution very elegant and I doubt it can be simplified further.
EDIT: Possible duplicate.

Thank you, I do not know how I missed 1/3. Yes, the question was a duplicate, I'll do my search more properly before posting next time.
